# Iterate through a string array in JSON

Tags: python, json, django

I'm looking to import data from a local JSON file into my DB Django.
However, I have a problem because my JSON file contains a String array for each element and I can't iterate it.

**Example of the JSON file:**

```
[
  {
    "key": "sword",
    "name": "Sword",
    "tier": 1,
    "tab": [
      "damages",
      "cac"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "bow",
    "name": "Bow",
    "tier": 1,
    "tab": [
       "damages",
       "distance"
    ]
  },
...
]
```

I import this data using a script as follows:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('json_file', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        with open(options['json_file']) as f:
            data_list = json.load(f)

        for data in data_list:
            Item.objects.get_or_create(
                key=data['key'],
                name=data['name'],
                tier=data['tier'],
            )

            for build in data['tab']:
                Build.objects.get_or_create(
                    key = build
                )
```

The above script does not work and I have the following error in the console:

```
KeyError: 'tab'
```

Comment: Do all dictionaries have a key `'tab'`, looks like some are missing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, it looks like not all dictionaries have a `"tab"` key. You can make the function more failsafe with:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('json_file', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        with open(options['json_file']) as f:
            data_list = json.load(f)

        for data in data_list:
            Item.objects.get_or_create(
                key=data['key'],
                name=data['name'],
                tier=data['tier'],
            )

            for build in data.get('tab', ()):
                Build.objects.get_or_create(
                    key = build
                )
```

Comment: Does build correspond to the string in tab?

Comment: @mamenejr: yes, that's correct. So for your sample data, it wil be `"damages", `"cac"`, `"distance"`.

Answer (score 1):

This error says that one of your instance doesn't have `tab` key. In that case you can skip creating `Build` instance with using `get` method with default empty list value `[]`:

```
for build in data.get('tab', []):
    Build.objects.get_or_create(
        key = build
    )
```